# Login names between sub domains in Active Directory

Tags: windows, active-directory, domain, subdomain

If I create two subdomains (sub1.domain.com and sub2.domain.com) to my parent domain (domain.com) can different users have the same login in the different subdomains? Or does logins need to be different across the forest.

- jsmith@domain.com
- jsmith@sub1.domain.com
- jsmith@sub2.domain.com

Is this perfectly fine or will sub 1 and 2 conflict with the parent domain. Or will all 3 conflict with eachother?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They can have the same samAccountName. The User Principal Name (UPN) must be unique forest-wide. So you can't have multiple jsmith@domain.com, but you can have jsmith@sub1.domain.com and jsmith@sub2.domain.com.